# Cast spark Row to String

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to read a timestamp column from Spark Dataset and cast it to String using appropriate format. Code looks like this:

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;
...
String result;

for (Row groupedRow : datasetGrouped.collectAsList()) {
    for (StructField sf : groupedRow.schema().fields()) {
        result = getDatasetFromRow(groupedRow).withColumn("fieldName", functions.date_format(col("fieldToGet"), "dd.MM.yyyy")).
                collectAsList().stream().findFirst().get().getAs("fieldName");
    }
}
...

private static Dataset<Row> getDatasetFromRow(Row row){
    List<Row> rowListToGetDataset = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> strListToGetDataset = new ArrayList<>();
    for(StructField sf : row.schema().fields()) {

        strListToGetDataset.add(row.getAs(sf.name()));

    }

    rowListToGetDataset.add(RowFactory.create(strListToGetDataset.toArray()));

    return SparkService.sqlContext().createDataFrame(rowListToGetDataset, row.schema());
}
```

This one is ugly and I'm looking for a solution, that doesn't create additional Dataset with timestamp field casted to String in format I need.
App uses Java Spark API, so any suggestions in Java please.
Spark ver: 2.3.1

Comment: what's the problem with the more common way of creating a new dataframe/dataset? it won't cause memory issues because the new dataframe is not stored in memory, and not even evaluated due to lazy evaluation

Comment: Can you add a sample input and desired output to your question? I'm having trouble seeing what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @mck I'm new with Spark.sql API, so I guess that there is always a more elegant (at least more short) way to get the result. In current case I thought that if I read a Row, I can manipulate it's fields in the same manner I can manipulate fields in Dataset, rather then take an extra step- create a new dataset and read rows from the new one. If code above looks as common way to solve my problem, then I will leave it as it is.

Comment: @CharlieFlowers I have a timestamp field in Dataset, which is used in creation of a URL path in HDFS. So when I try to read this field from Dataset and convert it to String this way: `result=row.getAs(fieldName).toString().replaceAll("^(.*?) .*", "$1");` all I can get is date in this format: `2018-07-03`. But result I need is: `03.07.2018`